# How to properly uploads files to certain api uisng curl in php

Tags: php

Am trying to add/upload files to monday.com api via curl in php but the code throws error `{"error_message":"Internal server error","status_code":500}`

[Monday Docs](https://api.developer.monday.com/docs/files-queries)

**here is the API Curl request**

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://api.monday.com/v2/file' \
--header 'Authorization: YourSuperSecretAPIKey' \
--form 'query="mutation add_file($file: File!, $item_id: Int!, $column_id: String!) {add_file_to_column (item_id: $item_id, column_id: $column_id, file: $file) {id}}"' \
--form 'variables="{\"item_id\":1104589438, \"column_id\": \"files\"}"' \
--form 'map="{\"image\":\"variables.file\"}"' \
--form 'image=@"/Users/alexsavchuk/Downloads/300px-All_Right_Then,_Keep_Your_Secrets.jpg"'
```

**Arguments Description of the API Variable**

```
item_id !Int    The item ID where the file will be added.
column_id !String   The column where the file will be added.
file !File  The file to upload.
```

**Here is my coding efforts**

```
$token = 'Token goes here';
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => 'https://api.monday.com/v2/file',
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array('query' => 'mutation ($file: File!) { add_file_to_column(file: $file, item_id: 279111, column_id: "files") { id } }','variables[file]'=> new CURLFILE('https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/05/26/12/30/baby-784608_960_720.jpg')),
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array('Authorization: ' . $token)));
$response = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
echo $response;
```

Comment: You know there are free online tools which can convert command line curl to php curl?

Comment: @ADyson please can you provide one